# Grammar vs convention in Objective-C property naming

Tags: objective-c, coding-style

Probably not important in the grand scheme of things, but I'm curious as to what some of the more veteran programmers think.

Say we have a boolean property to track whether Ads are Enabled. Since 'Ads' is plural the present-plural form '**are**' would be used for general writing.

However, in my code, all other boolean properties are prefixed with '**is**'. Example: *isUserLoggedIn*'.

**Q: Which is best: Uniformity or Grammar?**

```
// Uniform, but grammatically incorrect:
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isUserLoggedIn;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isAutoplayEnabled;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isAdsEnabled;

// or 

// Grammatically correct, but not uniform
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isUserLoggedIn;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isAutoplayEnabled;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL areAdsEnabled;
```

I went ahead with using **areAdsEnabled** because it bothered me less. Enlighten me if you think I'm wrong.

Comment: `areAdsEnabled`. Or maybe simply `adsEnabled`.

Comment: voting to close: "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Comment: I don't bother with the `is` prefix, most of the time it's no more grammatical - `if(foo.isUserLoggedIn)`? meh. Now `if(foo.userIsLoggedIn)` would be better, IMO.

Comment: You should be using `isFoo` as the getter, not the full property name anyway.

Answer (score 2):

EITHER adsEnabled only OR areAdsEnabled as a getter.

The main thing is, that you should only rename the GETTER here

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter=areAdsEnabled) BOOL adsEnabled;
```

Comment: I know that it is allowed, but I have a bad feeling about "voting to close" and answering simultaneously. In this case of "opinion based", only *your* opinion would be given.

Comment: @MartinR I answered because I wanted to show that he shouldn't rename the property but make use of the getter= attribute

Comment: that's why I have both